# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

i have spring mvc+jpa project. When I run this project and go to `/service` link i get excepiton. I'm try work with `@Autowired` but i get another exception, because use `applicationContext`

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ua.korbo.persistence.repository.PupilRepository] is defined
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    private PupilService pupilService;
    private PupilRepository pupilRepository;
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private void setUpField(){
        System.out.println("1");
        if (context == null){
            System.out.println("2");
            context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanClass.class);
            System.out.println("3");
        }
        System.out.println("4");
        if (pupilService == null){
            System.out.println("5");
            pupilService = context.getBean(PupilServiceImpl.class);
            System.out.println("6");
        }
        System.out.println("7");
        if (pupilRepository == null){
            System.out.println("8");
            System.out.printf(pupilRepository + " start");
            pupilRepository = context.getBean(PupilRepository.class);
            System.out.printf(pupilRepository+" end");
            System.out.println("9");
        }
    }    
@RequestMapping(value = "/service", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printService(Map<String, String> model){
        setUpField();
        pupilService.findAll();
        pupilService.setPupilRepositories(pupilRepository);
        pupilService.save(new Pupil("Name", "Last", "Email", "MSG", "Number"));
        model.put("key", "This is service!");
        return "print";
    }
}
```

Information from sout `setUpField`

```
1
2
08-Sep-2015 21:30:42.871 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
08-Sep-2015 21:30:42.902 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
08-Sep-2015 21:30:43.048 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] <unknown>.<unknown> HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-Sep-2015 21:30:43.048 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] <unknown>.<unknown> HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@229bbfd5
08-Sep-2015 21:30:43.055 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] <unknown>.<unknown> HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
08-Sep-2015 21:30:43.066 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.addEntityManagerFactory HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (default) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
3
4
5
6
7
8
null start
```

**Web Initializer**

```
public class MyWebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringRootConfig.class, PersistenceContext.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**Persistance context**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"persistence.repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class PersistenceContext {

    public PersistenceContext() {
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the datasource bean
     * */

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
        dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the entity manager factory
     * */
    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("entity");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the transaction manager
     * */
    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface PupilRepository extends CrudRepository<Pupil, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Your base package for `@EnableJPARepo` is set at `persistence.repository`, but spring is looking in different package - `com.ua.korbo.persistence.repository.PupilRepository`. Look into that.

Comment: @RohitJain, I made changes but it does not solve the problem

Comment: @BohdanOlehovich do you got the solution.